# What determines plot availability?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

I want to give X3AP a go, but a game of X3 is a big undertaking and I don't want to have to start all over again after discovering that some seemingly inconsequent decision I made 50 hours ago means I can't get the PHQ or something. What determines if I get access to particular plots? Do some starts offer more plots than others? Are there mutually exclusive plots or branches?

Comment: But that's the whole point is playing multiple times to get a bunch of endings

Comment: @DomenikVanbuskirk not for X3, this game is entirely different from most games.

Comment: @spartacus That would explain the need for this question then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Every start](http://www.egosoft.com/support/faq/faq_answer_en.php?answer=2167) type in X3:AP has the plot enabled except for the custom start.

For non Terran starts, there are are 3 plots lines, the main missions, and the hub missions, and the PHQ.  All are tied to reputation requirements:

- To start the Main plot, your argon rep has to be 4 or higher (Argon Advisor) and Terran rep has to be 0 or lower.
- To start the hub mission line, you must have completed the main plot, and then have Boron rank of queens guard or higher and have found Atreus HQ.
- To start the PHQ plot, you must have completed the main plot, and have a Teladi rep of Major Shareholder, and also own at least 1 station.  Also you must have found both the NNMC and Plutarch HQs.

For the Terran and Aldrin starts, there is only one mission:

- Operation Loose Ends requires you be at least a local councillor for the Terrans and a fight rank of 14 (Professional)

Comment: I just found this and it seems you're missing a few plots and requirements http://www.egosoft.com/support/faq/faq_answer_en.php?answer=2167 If you add that info to the question I will gladly accept.

Comment: @kotekzot huh neat, I wasn't aware they added a plot of some sorts for the terran/aldrin starts, that's nifty.

Comment: Also, this guide will let you unlock all of the secret game starts http://moscacr.ucoz.com/publ/4-1-0-3 It's for TC, but works equally well for AP, though it will also unlock some vestigial TC starts that may or may not work properly with the new plots.